# how to exclude jar file from getting installed using maven-install-plugin?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin, maven-install-plugin

I have a jar file created using maven-jar-plugin.

Is there a way to skip this jar file from getting installed in repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.2</version>
       <configuration>
         <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The reason this works is that the `install` plugin's *only* job is to take your artifact(s) and install them in your local repo.

In Maven, there are *main* artifacts and *attached* artifacts. I am not sure if you can suppress installation of the main artifact and only install the attached artifact, since assemblies are not required to provide a POM.

If this is what you really want to achieve, I would suggest breaking out the assembly to a separate artifact (with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`), have it depend on the jar-artifact you are trying to exclude and simply install that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it will skip the whole installation.

Comment: I have some other files like zip to be installed and I really want zip to be installed along with pom.xml.